# How do I create an editable field with a Save button on Magento Admin's Order detail page?

Tags: magento

I've already created a custom module that overrides the `sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml` layout file and creates a new field in the `sales_flat_order` table. Now I need figure out how to add a text input field to the order page:

[image]

The save button doesn't necessarily need to be right near the custom field and the field doesn't need to necessarily appear right where I put it in the graphic. Bottom line is, the administrator needs to be able to edit my new custom field in the admin.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Comments History block [image: Comments History block]

implementation - class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_History`, its template `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\history.phtml` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::addCommentAction()`. You should create similar block class with similar template and create controller with action which will save form data to your db field.